# Не применяется height:100%

Tags: html, css

Не срабатывает height:100%;

```css
.project-title{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #151417;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.project-name{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #626068;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.projectimg{
  border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
  width: 285px;
  height: 462px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.project-info h3{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #151417;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.project-info p{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #626068;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.project-info b{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #151417;
}
.project-info ul li{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 200%;
  color: #626068;
}
.project-info{
  width: 510px;
}
.project-icon{
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background: rgba(41, 185, 97, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.project-icon-block{
  margin-right: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.project-icon-block:last-child{
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.project-icon-text{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #626068;
}
.project-icons{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}
.project-product{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.project-blocks{
  display: flex;
}
.project-btn{
  background: #302D37;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.project-equipment{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #151417;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.project-equipment-text{
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #626068;
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.project-advantages{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.project-advantages-btn{
  background: #29B961;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 285px;
  height: 62px;
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.project-product{
  background: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.line{
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-product">
  <img class="projectimg" src="static/images/projectimage.png" alt="">
  <div class="project-blocks">
    <div class="project-info">
      <h3>ТЦ Бумана - сити</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever</p>
      <b>Преимущества проекта</b>
      <ul class="project-advantages">
        <li>Быстрый доступ к катлавану</li>
        <li>Собрана вся документация</li>
        <li>Установка заняла 24 ч</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="project-advantages-btn">О проекте</a>
    </div>
    <div class="project-buy">
      <h3 class="project-equipment">Оборудование</h3>
      <p class="project-equipment-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever</p>
      <div class="project-icons">
        <div class="project-icon-block">
          <div class="project-icon">
            <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M19.9062 1.15625H2.09375C1.57598 1.15625 1.15625 1.57598 1.15625 2.09375V19.9062C1.15625 20.424 1.57598 20.8438 2.09375 20.8438H19.9062C20.424 20.8438 20.8438 20.424 20.8438 19.9062V2.09375C20.8438 1.57598 20.424 1.15625 19.9062 1.15625Z" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              <path d="M11 1.15625V20.8438" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              <path d="M20.8438 11H1.15625" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              </svg>                    
          </div>
          <p class="project-icon-text">Окна</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-icon-block">
          <div class="project-icon">
            <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M19.9062 1.15625H2.09375C1.57598 1.15625 1.15625 1.57598 1.15625 2.09375V19.9062C1.15625 20.424 1.57598 20.8438 2.09375 20.8438H19.9062C20.424 20.8438 20.8438 20.424 20.8438 19.9062V2.09375C20.8438 1.57598 20.424 1.15625 19.9062 1.15625Z" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              <path d="M11 1.15625V20.8438" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              <path d="M20.8438 11H1.15625" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              </svg>                    
          </div>
          <p class="project-icon-text">Окна</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-icon-block">
          <div class="project-icon">
            <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M19.9062 1.15625H2.09375C1.57598 1.15625 1.15625 1.57598 1.15625 2.09375V19.9062C1.15625 20.424 1.57598 20.8438 2.09375 20.8438H19.9062C20.424 20.8438 20.8438 20.424 20.8438 19.9062V2.09375C20.8438 1.57598 20.424 1.15625 19.9062 1.15625Z" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              <path d="M11 1.15625V20.8438" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              <path d="M20.8438 11H1.15625" stroke="#29B961" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
              </svg>                    
          </div>
          <p class="project-icon-text">Окна</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="project-btn">В каталог</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как должно выглядить:

[image: Как должно выглядить]

Как выглядит у меня:

[image: Как выглядит у меня]

Comment: Что не так? Что не срабатывает?

Comment: @InDevX, речь идет кажется о линии (слева от оборудования) насколько я понимаю. Только я не понимаю, почему бы не сделать просто `border-left`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson так её вообще нет, о каких % тогда речь) border-left это да. но ещё структуру блоков тогда поменять надо, или отступы не так добавлять, не суть